# Слои в Svg при применении Drop Shadow

Tags: javascript, css3, svg, d3.js

Мне бы хотелось иметь затенение для графика, который я делаю с использованием `d3` и `SVG`, но у меня возникли проблемы с тенями, перекрывающими соседние элементы.
Смотрите изображение ниже, как оно выглядит в настоящее время. Обратите внимание на то, что шестиугольники в середине имеют различную высоту, потому что поверх некоторых из них отображаются тени.

Я хотел бы настроить тени таким образом, чтобы они отображались только на фоне, а не поверх других смежных шестиугольников.

Вот код демонстрирующий, как в настоящее время определяются тени:

```
var filter = defs.append("filter")
            .attr("id", "drop-shadow")
            .attr("height", "130%");

        // SourceAlpha refers to opacity of graphic that this filter will be applied to
        // convolve that with a Gaussian with standard deviation 3 and store result
        // in blur
        filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
            .attr("in", "SourceAlpha")
            .attr("stdDeviation", 1)
            .attr("result", "blur");

        // translate output of Gaussian blur to the right and downwards with 2px
        // store result in offsetBlur
        filter.append("feOffset")
            .attr("in", "blur")
            .attr("dx", 1)
            .attr("dy", 1)
            .attr("result", "offsetBlur");

        // overlay original SourceGraphic over translated blurred opacity by using
        // feMerge filter. Order of specifying inputs is important!
        var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge");

        feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
            .attr("in", "offsetBlur")
        feMerge.append("feMergeNode")
            .attr("in", "SourceGraphic");
```

Эти стили затем применяются к шестиугольникам:

`d3.select(this).style("filter", "url(#drop-shadow)")`

[image: Shadows overlapping hexagaons]

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/45558251/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Вам не нужно создавать целую кучу дубликатов в двух слоях.

Все, что вам нужно сделать, это обернуть все свои шестиугольники в группу `<g>` и применить к ним фильтр.

`<g filter="url(#drop-shadow)" transform="translate(150,0)">`

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="drop-shadow" width="150%" height="150%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>
      <feOffset in="blur" dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetBlur"/>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="offsetBlur"/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <rect x="75" y="75" width="50" height="50" fill="cyan"
        filter="url(#drop-shadow)"/>
  <rect x="75" y="25" width="50" height="50" fill="gold"
        filter="url(#drop-shadow)"/>
  <rect x="25" y="75" width="50" height="50" fill="lime"
        filter="url(#drop-shadow)"/>
  <rect x="25" y="25" width="50" height="50" fill="red"
        filter="url(#drop-shadow)"/>

  <g filter="url(#drop-shadow)" transform="translate(150,0)">
    <rect x="75" y="75" width="50" height="50" fill="cyan"/>
    <rect x="75" y="25" width="50" height="50" fill="gold"/>
    <rect x="25" y="75" width="50" height="50" fill="lime"/>
    <rect x="25" y="25" width="50" height="50" fill="red"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```